# view visible behind navigationbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have changed the default background image of my navigation bar like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"titlebarbg_square.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Why can I now see the background view above my navigationbar?**

It might not be clear in the image below, but look above the navigation bar and you can see the red background.

[image]

Comment: is your titlebarbg_square.png image of the correct size? 44px (88 for retina) height

Comment: Do you use Storyboard/InterfaceBuilder ? If yes, check that the Navigation Bar's x-coordinate is 0

Comment: actually, it is 320*48